# Passing address to firebase Realtime Database

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to upload the user selected address to Firebase Realtime Database. The goal is: after the address is in the firebase realtime data, the user will be able to retrieve the address information from Firebase, and the retrieved data will be viewed by the user and the user can click the address and apple Map is used to navigate to that position.

Now, I am confused that if I should pass the street name which is acquired by MKLocalSearchCompleter; or pass the coordinate, longitude and latitude, which is acquired by MKLocalSearchRequest.

What is the proper way to play with address data?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database can only store JSON types.

Since `MKLocalSearchCompleter` and `MKLocalSearchRequest` are not JSON types, they can't be stored in the database.

Longitude and latitude are floats, and street name is a string, so those are valid types to store in the database.

Which one of these is better really depends on your use-case. Since you're displaying them on the map, you'll likely want lat and lon. But if you want a clickable address, you'll likely also want the (more human readable) street name.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I appreciate it!